# Serializable and interfaces: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: java, android, serialization, interface

I have read various threads related to this topic on stackoverflow but none seem to address this particular problem I have.

I use the following object as a interface:

```
public class FailGroupCreateEvent implements Serializable {

    private OnEventListener mOnEventListener;

    public void setOnEventListener(OnEventListener listener) {
        mOnEventListener = listener;
    }

    public void doEvent() {
        if (mOnEventListener != null) {
            mOnEventListener.onEvent(); // event object :)
        }
    }

    public interface OnEventListener extends Serializable {
        void onEvent();
    }

}
```

It is there so that if a group fails to get created `Activity B`, it will notify `Activity A` and `Activity A` will load a snackbar to show a failure message.

In `Activity A`, I do the following:

```
FailGroupCreateEvent failGroupCreateEvent = new FailGroupCreateEvent();

FailGroupCreateEvent.OnEventListener failedToCreateGroup = new FailGroupCreateEvent.OnEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), getString(R.string.failed_group_create), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
    failGroupCreateEvent.setOnEventListener(failedToCreateGroup);
```

I then start `Activity B` using the following code and put the extra into the intent:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                intent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.failed_intent), failGroupCreateEvent);
                startActivity(intent);
```

In `ActivityB`, I do the following:

```
FailGroupCreateEvent failGroupCreateEvent;
if (//there is some type of network error) {
      failGroupCreateEvent.doEvent();
}
```

However, the FailGroupCreateEvent object is throwing this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.myapp, PID: 4720
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.myapp.interfaces.FailGroupCreateEvent)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1394)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644)
                                                     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
                                                     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669)
                                                     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7485)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2411)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
                                                     at com.adapter.InnerPlaceAdapter$1.onClick(InnerPlaceAdapter.java:282)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                  Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.myapp.activities.PlacesFragment
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1389)
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1341) 
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:644) 
                                                     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
                                                     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1034) 
                                                     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:669) 
                                                     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7485) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2411) 
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1496) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706) 
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016) 
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984) 
                                                     at com.adapter.InnerPlaceAdapter$1.onClick(InnerPlaceAdapter.java:282) 
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Why can I not pass this as a serializable object between the two activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tactically, you are trying to pass the activity itself and all that it is holding onto via your `Serializable`, courtesy of things like `getView()`.

Strategically, what you want does not work. `Serializable` is for writing things to files. A file cannot hold an activity, or a `View`, or an event listener. Now, Android happens to offer `Serializable` support for `Intent` extras, but that doesn't change the fundamental nature of `Serializable`. If it can't be written to a file, it won't work. In the best-case scenario, the recipient will wind up with *copies* of the objects, and they wouldn't be tied to the sender.

Depending on what's going on here, you either need to:

- Use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, or
- Use an event bus, or
- Don't make these two separate activities, but rather combine them into a single activity, if they are that tightly coupled (e.g., use fragments)

Comment: I think the best way forward for me is to use a localbroadcastmanager to do the pass the message between the two activities.

Comment: @Simon: That's an event bus, and it should work, though I don't recall having used it for inter-activity communications.